# Cannot get JSON results using PhoneGap and javascript on iPhone App but get results on android app using same code

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, json, cordova

currently i using this code in phonegap application

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://192.168.1.19:8080/searchMobile?categoryRequest=true", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {alert(xmlhttp.status);
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    var responseObject = eval("(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")");
    var results = responseObject.result;
    if (results != null)
    {
        var resLength = results.length;
        category.length = category.length + resLength;
        for ( var i = 0; i < resLength; i++)
        {
            category.options[category.length - (resLength - i)].innerHTML = results[i].categoryName;
            $(category).selectmenu("refresh");
      }
    }
}
```

this code is working in android but when i run this code on iphone it gives status 0 means doesn't work.
how can i overcome this problem 
many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as @Raymond Camden said make sure your url is [white listed in the .plist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide_ios). Second it is perfectly normal for you to get a status of 0 when doing AJAX from the file:// protocol. Webkit will set the status to 0 because you are doing a cross domain request which in a web browser would be blocked but in a web view, like PhoneGap uses, is perfectly okay. So in this case 0 == 200. Third get rid of eval, if you are returning JSON data use JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) as it is [much safer](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: thank you very much simon i got it thank u it works... but how can we make build for ios in phonegap build it shows me "requires a siging key"....  many thanks

Comment: and there is one more problem.. how to add url to the whitelist in .plist file at run time because in my application i using different-2 domain name for fetching data so how can i do this please help..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the URL to the whitelist.